# 8051 port pin become high or not

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

Is there any way so we know which bit or pin is high or not in 8051 port without checking particular bit?

For example: P0.0 is become high.

I know the way by checking particular bits means P0.0.

Comment: This questions seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the *real* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you need "any other way to do"?

Comment: Hi,
I have 7 LEDs connected on Port 0 and I want the status of led on P0 port and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is a little bit broad. Maybe you could use something like this:

```
if (Port0 & 0x80)
{
    ....                //Pin P0.7 is high
}
else
{     
    ....                //Pin0.7 is low
}
```

Comment: I think it's better if I check particular bit.???!
Don't have any other good idea

Comment: but you won't something like that: if (P0.7 == 1) ?

Comment: Yeah particular bit checking but not by if else

Comment: and also not 'switch/case' ? Really crazy question. What would you like to do, when not using if-statement. Normaly you check a Bit and than do something or not.

Comment: led(connected at port of 8051) . any one of either off or on anytime.thats why I need status of them on particular  port pin and save it.youare right we can use if else or switch case but any other way in which we can get status in one or few lines of code??